# Input a value to database then automatically get the value without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, reload

```html
<form method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="display" id="example">
  <tr>
   <td><center>The Value</td>   
            <td><center>Choose Value</td>   
  </tr>

 
  <tr>
<?php
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `mydatabase` ");
 while($row_array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {  
   $the_value= $row_array['db_value'];
    }

echo "<td>".$the_value."</td>";

?>
<td>
<input type="text" name="valuename">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Enter Value">
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
 if ( array_key_exists ( 'sub', $_POST )  ) 
 {

  $value_go_to_database=$_POST['valuename'];


$func=mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `db`.`mydatabase` (`db_value`) VALUES ('$value_go_to_database') ");

    }
?>
```

---

Everything in my code here works sorry if some are missing here in this or so, i just want an idea how to put the value to the database without refreshing/reloading the page and then automatically get that value and put it in my table.
**Its like on the submit click, it automatically sends the value/data to my database then poof also shows itself in my table as well without the refresh/reload of the page part.**
I'm new, dont know how to use AJAX trying to read it for a while i cant quite get it how to insert it to my coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use Ajax. Search on google.

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Post values and get response in ajax. If you are already using the jquery library, serialize form data and use $.post() to ajax submit or search how to post data using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what it's like to be confused with encountering AJAX for the first time. It's a really simple concept though and is more tedious, than it is hard. Here is an example however to help you on your way:

I strongly recommend using jQuery for this as it wraps all of these functions into an easy to use syntax.

```
<form id="something">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').click(function () {
        var values = $('form').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({url: 'http://yoururl.fake/somewhere.php', // The url to send the request to
                type: 'POST', // This tells the AJAX function which type of request to send
                data: values, // This is where you send your data to the server
                success: function (data) {
                    // `data` now contains your response from the server. 
                    // It can be html, JSON, plain text, or whatever you choose.
                    // if `data` is html then you can simply insert it as such:
                    $('body').append(data); // Or wherever you want to put it.
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Something went wrong and here is your chance to nicely tell the user that.
                    alert('something went wrong');
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```